# Live migrate a libvirt/kvm virtual machine with both local and shared storage

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, live-migration

I want to use both local (for better performance where it matters) and shared (for big slow disks) storage for a VM. Is it possible to live migrate such a VM?

If the storage was pure local, the migration command would be

```
virsh migrate vm qemu+ssh://new.hv.ip --copy-storage-all
```

This would copy the disk images prior to migrating the VM.

If the storage was pure shared, then the --copy-storage-all option is not needed.

So, what if one disk is local and another is shared? Won't copy-storage-all corrupt the disk on shared storage?

Comment: Rather than assign the shared storage via the hypervisor, why not use iSCSI and let the VM address/access it directly? The circumvents the whole problem.